# non keyword arg after keyword arg python classes

Tags: python, class, tkinter, radio-button

I cannot understand what's happening with that code...Please help new in Python! What does it mean by saying non keyword arg after keyword arg in python? What can I do to run my code below? The error invokes when calling the class CreatingWindowForEachLesson with the parameters needed for the initialisation of that class. Help!

```
class WindowSector():
    global root 
    def __init__(self):
        self.master=master
        self.startwindow()
    def startwindow(self):
        self.l=Label(self.master,text="Επιλογή Τομέα Σπουδών")
        self.l.pack()
        self.v=IntVar()
        self.v.set(1)
        self.r1=Radiobutton(self.master,text="ΤΟΜΕΑΣ ΣΥΣΤΗΜΑΤΩΝ ΑΥΤΟΜΑΤΟΥ ΕΛΕΓΧΟΥ",variable=self.v, value=1)
        self.r1.pack(anchor=W)
        self.r1.invoke()
        self.r2=Radiobutton(self.master,text="ΤΟΜΕΑΣ ΗΛΕΚΤΡΟΝΙΚΗΣ ΚΑΙ ΥΠΟΛΟΓΙΣΤΩΝ",variable=self.v, value=2)
        self.r2.pack(anchor=W)
        self.r2.invoke()
        self.r3=Radiobutton(self.master,text="ΤΟΜΕΑΣ ΤΗΛΕΠΙΚΟΙΝΩΝΙΩΝ ΚΑΙ ΠΛΗΡΟΦΟΡΙΑΣ",variable=self.v, value=3)
        self.r3.pack(anchor=W)
        self.r3.invoke()
        self.r4=Radiobutton(self.master,text="ΤΟΜΕΑΣ ΣΥΣΤΗΜΑΤΩΝ ΗΛΕΚΤΡΙΚΗΣ ΕΝΕΡΓΕΙΑΣ",variable=self.v, value=4)
        self.r4.pack(anchor=W)
        self.r4.invoke()
        self.b=Button(self.master,text="Συνέχεια")
        self.b.pack(anchor=E)
    def ButtonClick(self):
        global choice,root,saeA7,saeB7,saeG7,yA7,yB7,yG7,tpA7,tpB7,tpG7,eA7,eB7,eG7 
        if (self.v.get())==1:
            choice=CreatingWindowForEachLesson(root,tomeas="ΣΥΣΤΗΜΑΤΩΝ ΑΥΤΟΜΑΤΟΥ ΕΛΕΓΧΟΥ",saeA7,saeB7,saeG7)
            self.master.quit()
        elif (self.v.get())==2:
            choice=CreatingWindowForEachLesson(root,tomeas="ΗΛΕΚΤΡΟΝΙΚΗΣ ΚΑΙ ΥΠΟΛΟΓΙΣΤΩΝ")#,yA7,yB7,yG7)
            self.master.quit()
        elif (self.v.get())==3:
            choice=CreatingWindowForEachLesson(root,tomeas="ΤΗΛΕΠΙΚΟΙΝΩΝΙΩΝ ΚΑΙ ΠΛΗΡΟΦΟΡΙΑΣ")#,tpA7,tpB7,tpG7)
            self.master.quit()
        elif (self.v.get())==4:
            choice=CreatingWindowForEachLesson(root,tomeas="ΣΥΣΤΗΜΑΤΩΝ ΗΛΕΚΤΡΙΚΗΣ ΕΝΕΡΓΕΙΑΣ")#,eA7,eB7,eG7)
            self.master.quit()
```

Comment: You are using `tomeas=...` in your `CreatingWindowForEachLesson()` calls followed by positional arguments. What is the signature for `CreatingWindowForEachLesson()`?

Comment: Martijn the CreatingWindowForEachLesson() has in the constructor a root,tomeas,list1,list2,list3

Comment: Then just drop the `tomeas=` part; no need to use a keyword argument here.

Comment: tomeas->text that says which sector the student chooses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
choice=CreatingWindowForEachLesson(root,tomeas="ΣΥΣΤΗΜΑΤΩΝ ΑΥΤΟΜΑΤΟΥ ΕΛΕΓΧΟΥ",saeA7,saeB7,saeG7)
```

When you include assignments in your arguments, what your really doing is creating a dictionary. You need to place this after your arguments without an assignment. Make sure your other methods follow this same rule:

```
choice=CreatingWindowForEachLesson(root,saeA7,saeB7,saeG7, tomeas="ΣΥΣΤΗΜΑΤΩΝ ΑΥΤΟΜΑΤΟΥ ΕΛΕΓΧΟΥ")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That one worked! Thanks for the help and for the explanation too Malik!

Comment: Anytime, I see you have a few other comments in the same incorrect fashion. Be sure to fix those if you end up using them.